# Could a gas giant the size of Neptune or Uranus harbor intelligent life?

Tags: aliens, gas-giants

If possible, what are some ways they could create tools? Assuming the gas giant is in the habitable zone and has a lot of water vapor in its atmosphere, receiving the same amount of sunlight Earth does. And by intelligent life I mean as intelligent as Humans. I imagine this species would be like a giant floating octopus creature with tentacles, and feeding off of microscopic organisms floating in the air.

Comment: https://what-if.xkcd.com/138/ and https://what-if.xkcd.com/139/

Comment: Define intelligent life.

Comment: Hi Stephanie, there just isn't too enough information to answer your question.  There are just lots of possible answers to your many questions.  Describing the kind of life you expect to see on this gas giant will help a lot in formulating an answer.

Comment: I believe you may have a good question here, but it needs some editing to be suitable for our Q&A format. Your title asks whether the gas giant could harbor intelligent life, but the body poses some other sub-questions (which is OK, as long as they support the main question). As it sits, unfortunately your question is too broad and (pardon the gaseous pun) a little nebulous on what you're asking. I suggest you edit your question and add as much detail as you can about what qualifies as "intelligent life" so that when the answers come in, it'll be possible to identify the best one.

Comment: What i'm really trying to ask is if a technologically advanced species can exist on a gas giant planet. I figure a Jupiter like gas giant has to much radiation and not much water in its atmosphere, so I chose a Neptune or Uranus like gas giant.

Comment: Well I tried being as descriptive as possible..

Comment: Hey! I was writing a detailed answer to this question when ... well ... it got closed and I was informed no more answers would be accepted. Sigh. Yes, Stephanie, your question is quite vague. You should add these details to make it more productive and meaningful. a- distance of the planet from it's sun. b- distance of the target moon from the planet c- composition of the planet (specially the atmosphere and the core) d- composition of the moon. If you add these details, it would be very much easier for us to provide you with an answer.

Comment: [Manta's Gift](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/216441.Manta_s_Gift) by Timothy Zahn has some similarities to what you're looking for. Here are a couple ideas to help you fix the question. A large gas giant could exist outside the habitable zone, as they can generate their own heat as they get more massive. They could be tool users, but it's a gas giant, so what do you have to build tools with? Also, because of the mass, gravity may be higher, which means higher escape velocity will be needed. For materials to build stuff you could have floating vegetation? No metals, so no space...

Comment: From the question it looks like intelligent = capable of creating tools, using tools to make better tools, and sharing knowledge. @Stephanie?